# Confidence Interval of COCOMO II Model

Tags: project-management, estimation, software-estimation

It is my understanding that COCOMO II model provides only one-point estimate.  So, is it possible to come up with a confidence level when using COCOMO II model?  What I am looking for is something like "with 95% confidence, it will take from xxx hours to yyy hours to complete a project."

Thanks,

Long

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dr. Barry Boehm, father of COCOMO II, responded to this question via email and I would like to share it here.  By default, the confidence interval of COCOMO II model is +/-25%.

Comment: Doesn't seem like an accurate interval...